# Trouble with binding events to Bootstrap 3 (button.js) button radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble getting the correct value from a segmented control I made with the radio button component of button.js in Twitter Bootstrap 3. When I bind a click event to the segmented control that runs $.serialize() on the parent form, it return the unchecked value of the radio button along with all the other correct values from the other inputs.

I suspect it might be related to the fact that I can't bind this event directly to the segmented control's input. When I tried to bind the event directly to the input I didn't get a response back, so I bound it to the label.

Here's an example of the problem in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stevekas/9w94pL4o/

```
<form id="form">
    <div id="radios">
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="major-category">
                <input facet="exclusive" type="radio" name="hipsum" value="hashtag" />hashtag</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="major-category">
                <input facet="exclusive" type="radio" name="hipsum" value="farm-to-table" />farm-to-table</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="major-category">
                <input facet="exclusive" type="radio" name="hipsum" value="gastropub" />gastropub</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ #radios -->
    <div id="segmented-control" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
            <input type="radio" name="segmented-control" id="roof" value="roof" autocomplete="off" checked />roof</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="segmented-control" id="party" value="party" autocomplete="off" />party</label>
    </div>
    <!--/ #segmented-control -->
</form>


<script>
    $('.radio input').on('click', function () {
        var data = $('#form').serialize();
    });

    $('#segmented-control label').on('click', function () {
        var data = $('#form').serialize();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Consider binding to the `change` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens because the click for the label is processed before the click for the input (the label is higher in the DOM tree).

You can force debug to be called after all the events have been processed using setTimeout() without any delay, like this:

```
$('#segmented-control label').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        debug();
    }, 0);
});
```

This works because setTimeout() enqueues a new event, which will be run after all the current pending ones.